# Angular ngrx Store data not being displayed

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I followed numerous tutorials to create the following project: I would like to display a food menu that is obtained from an API call. You may notice some additional functions that are not used or are implemented in an old way.

My main focus is to solve the problem of Search Food method which is supposed to make an API call retrieve the data and store it in `Menu[]`. The data in menu is the data I would like list in my application.

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "burger",
    "description": "del delddd",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "sandwich",
    "description": "del del",
    "price": 12
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "fries",
    "description": "dl",
    "price": 3
  }
]
```

reducer.ts

```
import { Food } from '../models/food.model';
import { Menu } from '../models/menu.model';

// importing Actions
import * as FoodActions from './menu.action';

export interface State {
    loading: boolean;
    results: Menu[];
    selectedFood: Food;
    foodList: Food[];
};

const initialState: State =  {
    loading: false,
    results: [],
    selectedFood: null,
    foodList: []
}

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: FoodActions.Actions): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FoodActions.SEARCH: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        }
        case FoodActions.SEARCH_DONE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                results: action.payload.menu
            }
        }
        case FoodActions.FETCH_FOOD: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        }
        case FoodActions.FETCH_FOOD_DONE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                selectedFood: action.payload
            }
        }
        case FoodActions.ADD_FOOD: {
            return {
                ...state,
                foodList: [...state.foodList, state.selectedFood]
            }
        }
        case FoodActions.GET_FOOD: {
            return {
                ...state,
                selectedFood: state.foodList[action.payload]
            }
        }


        default: {
            return state;
        }

    }
}
```

menu.action.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Action, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Food } from '../models/food.model';
import { Menu } from '../models/menu.model';

// True while fetching data from API
export const LOADING = 'Food Load';

// Searching Food via Food Search API
export const SEARCH = 'Food Search';
export const SEARCH_DONE = 'Food Search Done';

// Fetching Food Details via Food Report API
export const FETCH_FOOD = 'Fetch Food';
export const FETCH_FOOD_DONE = 'Fetch Food Done';

// Adding Food to My-Food-list
export const ADD_FOOD = 'Add Food';

// Getting Food Details from My-Food-list
export const GET_FOOD = 'Get Food';

// Removing Food to My-Food-list
export const REMOVE_FOOD = 'Remove Food';



export class Search implements Action {
    readonly type = SEARCH;
    constructor() { };
}

export class SearchDone implements Action {
    readonly type = SEARCH_DONE;
    constructor(public payload: {menu:Menu[]}) { };
}

export class FetchFood implements Action {
    readonly type = FETCH_FOOD;
    constructor(public payload: string) {}
}

export class FetchFoodDone implements Action {
    readonly type = FETCH_FOOD_DONE;
    constructor(public payload: Food) {}
}

export class AddFood implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_FOOD;
    constructor() {}
}

export class GetFood implements Action {
    readonly type = GET_FOOD;
    constructor(public payload: string) {}
}

export class RemoveFood implements Action {
    readonly type = REMOVE_FOOD;
    constructor(public payload: Food) {}
}


export type Actions =   Search | SearchDone 
                        | AddFood | RemoveFood 
                        | FetchFood | FetchFoodDone 
                        | GetFood;
```

effects.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Effect, Actions, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map, take, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Menu } from './../models/menu.model'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


import * as FoodActions from "./menu.action";
import { FoodService } from "../services/food.service";



@Injectable()

export class FoodEffects {

constructor(private actions$: Actions, 
    private foodService: FoodService) {}    

// Listen for the 'SEARCH' action
 @Effect() 
searchFood$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(

 ofType<FoodActions.Search>(FoodActions.SEARCH),
 switchMap(() => {
    return this.foodService.searchFood()
 .pipe(map((results: Menu[]) => new FoodActions.SearchDone({menu: results}))
                // catch(() => of(new FoodActions.FetchFoodFail()))
 );
})
);

@Effect() 
fetchFood$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
 // Listen for the 'FETCH_FOOD' action
.ofType(FoodActions.FETCH_FOOD)
.map((action: FoodActions.FetchFood) => action.payload)
.switchMap(query => {
    return this.foodService.fetchFood(query)
    .map(food => new FoodActions.FetchFoodDone(food));
    // catch(() => of(new FoodActions.FetchFoodFail()))
});
}
```

MODELS
menu.model.ts

```
    export interface IMenu{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;

}

export class Menu implements IMenu {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;

}
```

food.model.ts

```
export interface FoodItem{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    price: string;
}

export class Food implements FoodItem{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    price: string;
    constructor(obj?: any){
        this.id = obj.id || '';
        this.name = obj.ndbno || '';
        this.price = obj.price || '';
    }
}
```

SERVICES
food.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Food } from '../models/food.model';
import { Menu } from '../models/menu.model';
@Injectable()
export class FoodService {
  // apiKey: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) { 
    // this.apiKey = 'XdagYlZrqyQtcLVstZl5fleZfzgFqK3ukMtWkPpZ';

  }

  searchFood(): Observable<Menu[]> {
    const url = 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/waelhosn/Circular/menu';

    return this.http.get(url)
                        // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .map((res:Response) => {return res.json()})

                         //...errors if any
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));


  }

  fetchFood(query: string): Observable<Food> {
    const url = 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/waelhosn/Circular/menu';

    return this.http.get(url)
    .pipe(map(this.extractData))
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
  }

  private extractData(res: Response): Food {
    const body = res.json().report.foods[0];
    return new Food(body);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errorMsg: string;
    if(error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() ||  '';
      const err = body.error ||  JSON.stringify(body);
      errorMsg = err;
    } else {
      errorMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
  }

  }
```

store.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Food } from '.././models/food.model';
import { Menu } from '.././models/menu.model';
import { FoodService } from '.././services/food.service';
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import * as fromRoot from ".././actions/reducer";
import * as Actions from '.././actions/menu.action';

@Injectable()
export class StoreService {

  state: Observable<fromRoot.State>;
  constructor(private foodService: FoodService, private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) { 
  this.state = this.store;
  }


  searchFood() {
    this.store.dispatch(new Actions.Search());
  }

  fetchFood(id) {
    this.store.dispatch(new Actions.FetchFood(id));
  }

  getFood(id) {
    this.store.dispatch(new Actions.GetFood(id));
  }

  addBasket() {
    this.store.dispatch(new Actions.AddFood());
  }

  removeBasket(food: Food) {
    this.store.dispatch(new Actions.RemoveFood(food));
  }
```

}

COMPONENTS

search-results.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Menu } from '../models/menu.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AppState } from './../app.state';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromRoot from '../actions/reducer';
import * as Actions from '../actions/menu.action';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-results',
  templateUrl: './search-results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-results.component.css']
})
export class SearchResultsComponent implements OnInit {

  results: Observable<Menu[]>;
  loading: Observable<Boolean>;

  constructor( private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.results = this.store.select(state => state.menu);
    this.loading = this.store.select(state => state.loading);
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

search-results.component.html

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <div class="subheader">
      <span style="font-weight:500">Results</span>
    </div>
    <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="loading | async" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
    <div class="search-results">
      <mat-list>
        <mat-list-item class="search-result-item" *ngFor="let result of results$ | async" [routerLink]="['/search', result.id]">
          <span class="search-result-item-name">{{result.name}}</span>
        </mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
    </div>
  </div>
```

search-input.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromRoot from '../actions/reducer';
import * as Actions from '../actions/menu.action';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'

import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switch';
import { AppState } from '../app.state';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-input',
  templateUrl: './search-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-input.component.css']
})
export class SearchInputComponent implements OnInit {


    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { }

    ngOnInit() { 
      this.store.dispatch(new Actions.Search());
    }

}
```

search-input.component.html (the below code is simply going to be disregarded since i will not be using a search input. I want the results to appear directly)

```
<div class="search-input-container">
    <input type="search" class="search-input"  mdInput placeholder="Search foods..." [routerLink]="['/search']">
</div>
```

Link to StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghtroq

Comment: Please add a StackBlitz example to make it clear what you're doing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tytdbu

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghtroq